# Why is it not 'A and B is similar'?

Tags: grammar

The statement 'A and B are similar' feels natural. It denotes that object A and object B have something in common.

The statement 'A and B is similar' doesn't feel right.

But why? When you think about it closely, a statement like 'A and B are similar' is very different from a statement like 'A and B are red.' The former expresses a relation between A and B, whereas the latter is using a single statement to attribute a property to both A and B.

Furthermore, the statement 'A and B are similar' can be viewed as attributing a property to the *pair* (A, B); in other words, it can be viewed as a shortening of the phrase 'The pair (A, B) is a pair of similar objects.' Here, we are attributing a property to a single object, and thus use the word 'is.'

Final note: The inspiration for this question comes from a humorous student's answer to an exercise. The exercise asked to prove that two things were isomorphic; i.e 'Prove that A and B are isomorphic.' The student's response was: 'A is, but B isn't.'

Comment: A is similar to B is also fine. But it doesn't matter if something is a "shortening" of something else. It only matters what form the thing as given takes.

Comment: In the answer you mention, it's only "clever" because of a play on the unstated assumption that A and B are isomorphic to *each other*. Instead of assuming that, it's answering the question to prove that A and B are both isomorphic to an unstated *something else*. (But while interesting, no proof is given for that answer either.)

Comment: @JasonBassford What do you mean by "it doesn't matter if something is a shortening of something else"? re the student: the question was asking the student to prove that A and B were isomorphic to one another. There was no other thing. The student misunderstood that this use of the word 'is' is not attributing the same property to two objects, but rather expressing a relation between objects. With absolutely no understanding of the word 'isomorphic,' this is an understandable error. Hence my question of why, as this confusion can easily arise.

Comment: It was in response to your statement "in other words, it can be viewed as a shortening of the phrase." I meant that just because a long version of something uses a plural, it doesn't mean that the shorter version of the same thing would also use a plural. It's not the concept that singularity or plurality applies to, it's the actual syntax used in any given phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassford Ah, I see. Yes, this answers the question. I do also have a sort of philosophical question as to why english chooses to use the word 'are' for both of these concepts, rather than having separate words. It seems to me that these two uses of 'are' are fundamentally different. Do you know of a place I can ask about something like this? Or ask about how other languages approach such a thing?

Comment: You can certainly determine *how* other languages refer to things—but for *why* any language is the way it is, you may find some things through etymology and linguistics (https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/); however, I don't think you'll find an answer to this specific question anywhere. (I could be wrong.)

Comment: I believe it would be logical to say: "[A and B] **is** similar *to [C and D]*. Where A and B / *C and D* are treated as single units or sets.

Answer (score 0):

One *is* singular. Two or more *are* plural. "Are" is used whenever you're referring to multiple items, regardless of what property you're attributing to them.

http://ask.dailygrammar.com/Is-vs-Are.html

Comment: Thanks. I know this, but the question is more of a 'why'? If the answer is just 'that's how things are' then I guess that's okay.